# Keycloak unable to synchronize with LDAP: Synchronization ignored as it's already in progress

Tags: ldap, keycloak

I am using Keycloak with LDAP integration. I was synchronizing users successfully from ActiveDirectory. Then at some point when synchronizing all users, I started getting the error: Synchronization ignored as it's already in progress (in fact it is part of the success message) and users are not synchronised. Just before starting to get this error, I played a bit with LDAP provider Edit mode (not sure it's related to the problem).I set it to WRITEABLE, then to UNSYNCED. I deleted one of the users that were previously imported from LDAP, then I switched back to READ_ONLY and tried to get back the deleted user but instead got the synchronization issue. Any idea why I am receiving this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that this was a simple configuration issue. User federation provider property "Import Users" must be On. If users are synced, and then this property is turned Off, further attempts to synchronize users will get the message "Success! Sync of users finished successfully. Synchronization ignored as it's already in progress". The solution is to turn "Import Users" back to On. Thanks to the smart QA engineer who discovered this:)

Answer (score 0):

did you checked the realm settings? I saw the same error and looking in the keycloak logs, showed me that a email in LDAP was not unique. So I disabled "login via email" in realm settings and "allowed duplicate emails" and it's working again

Comment: I do not see such an error in the logs. Moreover, I defined another user federation provider which is identical to the faulty one. That is, both providers sync from the same Active Directory. I am able to sync users successfully via the second provider while the first still gives the "Synchronization ignored as it's already in progress" error. So my realm settings are fine I believe.

Comment: really strange.